# Amazon S3 - static IP or proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, ip

Is there a way with **Amazon S3** to have proxy access or a static(public) IP address?

I have a client wanting to stream **CDN** content to his application which is behind his IP rules on his router.

Is there a way to do this on **AWS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can access AWS S3 via proxy server. Since your proxy IP is static, it can vaild firewall rules.